# Using Scanner with sequence of Integers

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a program to take a sequence of integers from console, e.g.

```
1 5 3 4 5 5 5 4 3 2 5 5 5 3
```

then compute the number of occurrences and print the following output:

```
0 - 0
1 - 1
2 - 1
3 - 3
4 - 2
5 - 7
6 - 0
7 - 0
8 - 0
9 - 0
```

where the second number is the number of occurrences of the first number.

Code:

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Scanner chopper = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a list of number: ");

    int[] numCount = new int[10];
    int number;

    while (chopper.hasNextInt()) {
        number = chopper.nextInt();
        numCount[number]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " - " + numCount[i]);
    }
}
```

But after inputing the sequence, we must type a non-integer character and press "Enter" to terminate the Scanner and execute the "for" loop. Is there any way that we don't have to type a non-integer character to terminate the Scanner?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to terminate Scanner when input is complete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206813/how-to-terminate-scanner-when-input-is-complete)

Comment: @user3681996 please specify what you want the user to do to terminate the program ? You wan't him to enter "end" for example ? or maybe a sentinel value 99999?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard that would be part of an answer in form of an explanation about why this can't just work when using `Scanner`.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard The user types integer sequence and press enter to terminate the program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get out by pressing Enter followed by Control-D.

If you don't want to do that, then there's no other way with a `Scanner`.

You will have to read the input by some other way, for example with a `BufferedReader`:

```
String line = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
Scanner chopper = new Scanner(line);
```

Even better (inspired by [@user3512478](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3512478/user3512478)'s approach), with two Scanners, without `BufferedReader`:

```
Scanner chopper = new Scanner(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
```

Comment: Thanks, I got that. Put 'Scanner chopper = new Scanner(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());' after 'System.out.println("Enter a list of number: ");'

Answer (score 0):

Best way IMO:

```
String str;
Scanner readIn = new Scanner(System.in);
str = readIn.nextLine();
String[] nums = str.split(" ");
int[] finalArray = new int[nums.length];
for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    finalArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
return finalArray;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Best way: Not just for this pattern, for any kind of sequence input recognition, modify delimiter of `Scanner` object to get required sequence recognized.

Here, in this case, change chopper delimiter to whitespace character (Spaces). i.e `"\\s"`. You can also use `"\\s*"` for specifying zero or more occurrence of whitespace characters

This makes Scanner to check for spaces rather than waiting for Enter key stroke.

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Scanner chopper = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\s"); \\ Delimiter changed to whitespace.
    System.out.println("Enter a list of number: ");

    int[] numCount = new int[10];
    int number;

    while (chopper.hasNextInt()) {
        number = chopper.nextInt();
        numCount[number]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " - " + numCount[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using a for loop.

```
for (int i:1; i<10;i++) {
     chopper.hasNextInt()
     number = chopper.nextInt();
     numCount[number]++;
}
```

From Oracle Doc it says: 
A scanning operation may block waiting for input.
Both hasNext and next methods may block waiting for further input

Comment: Why the negative point ?   I tryied this example and it works perfectly.   
I added some exception handler and logging lines but it stays the same.   
     int[] numCount = new int[10];   
     int number;   
     for (int i=1; i<10;i++) {   
       chopper.hasNextInt();   
       try{
        number = chopper.nextInt();
        numCount[number]++;
       }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(chopper.next());
       }
  }

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         System.out.println(i + " - " + numCount[i]);
     }
 }

Comment: "*I used my example and it works perfectly*" no it doesn't. This code assumes that there must be 9 integers in input so (1) it will require user to provide 9 digits, (2) it will ignore rest of numbers starting from 10th one. Instead of `for (int i:1; i<10;i++)` you may want to use `while (scanner.hasNextInt())`.