# Terminate scanner input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'd like to implement Scanner termination when input is complete. As a termination I choose blank line - just enter key. However for some reason (unknown to me) below implementation doesn't work. Do you have any idea why? Or maybe you know better solution?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (!scanner.nextLine().startsWith("\n")) {
     // code
}
// code after press just Enter
```

I tried also:

```
while (!scanner.nextLine().equals("\n"))
```

... or:

```
while (scanner.nextLine().isEmpty())
```

Nothing works...

PS. Some of you may think that I duplicate this topic:
[How to terminate Scanner when input is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206813/how-to-terminate-scanner-when-input-is-complete)

However I do it on purpose, because I'm asking now about specific implementation, not a general Scanner termination.

Comment: Store the `scanner.nextLine()` to a variable and check if it's not empty, enter loop and directly use the variable...

Comment: Are you trying to get the user to input one line of text and when they hit enter, your code moves on?

Comment: @Codebender: Thanks for your suggestion, but I tried this with isEmpty() method. It didn't give any result.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry: truly speaking, I don't get it. Could you write some code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for scanner.nextLine().length() == 0

Since \n is the line terminator, that's not going to be returned by the scanner, similar concept to parsing strings or using StringTokenizer.  You just need to look for a zero-length string.

Comment: Your concept seems to be awesome! Thanks! However it doesn't give me any result, I don't know why. Any suggestions? 

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.nextLine().length() == 0) {
          //code
}
// this code doesn't work

Comment: Your initial code wasn't assigning the line to a temporary variable before analyzing the empty line.  By doing scanner.nextLine().length() in one call, you've consumed/analyzed/lost the line in a single step.  I was just taking what you had, but wanted to see if you realized!  :)

Comment: If I write smth like this below I will lose first line of input. 


int nextLine = scanner.nextLine().length();


                 while(nextLine == 0) {


                 // code


                 nextLine = scanner.nextLine().length();  


}

Comment: Look, if you want someone to do your homework, hire a tutor, it's a simple problem of always capturing the input prior to evaluating the data.