# Running code taking undefined number of inputs in Netbeans

Tags: java

I have a code that takes input using scanner but the number of input is not defined. How to run the code in Netbeans?

The code is as follows:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    // print the token
    System.out.println(scan.next());
}
scan.close();
```

When I run the code, it is only taking input and no further processing is done.

Comment: In your code, You are just printing the input to output stream. what type of processing do you want?

Comment: For the record: this has **nothing** to do with the IDE that you are using. No need to put a netbeans tag on a pure java question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to terminate Scanner when input is complete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206813/how-to-terminate-scanner-when-input-is-complete)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to take input, then print it?

Put in something like:

```
String s = scan.next();
```

before the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your input looks like, so maybe try changing

```
hasNextLine()
```

to just

```
hasNext()
```

Comment: input is like pear \n hamlet \n amleth \n dormitory