# Java Taking Multiple Line Input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How do I go about taking input that is multiple lines, such as

```
4 2 9
1 4 2
9 8 5
```

and placing it into an array of that is big enough to hold each line with no empty positions, or an arraylist. I've tried many ways to do this and cannot find a solution.
For example, if the user copied and pasted the above snippet as input, I want an array or arraylist to hold

```
["4 2 9", "1 4 2", "9 8 5"]
```

Comment: @OP: _I've tried many ways to do this ..._ Show your trial code to us.

Comment: use `arraylist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `nextLine`

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    list.add(s.nextLine());
}

System.out.println(list);
```

Note that the scanner will keep prompting for input. To stop this, you need to enter an end of line character. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16206876/5133585) for how to do this.

Example input/output:

```
4 2 9
1 4 2
9 8 5
^D
[4 2 9, 1 4 2, 9 8 5]
```

Comment: That works but is there a way I can do it where the user doesn't have to manually terminate the program? I want the compiler itself to know when there is no more input. If there is no way then that's okay, thank you

Comment: There is no way to do that, I'm afraid. @HarunFeraidon

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
 list.add(str);
}
```

Comment: While loop never terminates and is constantly checking for new lines

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read the input from console.

Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String str = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(str);
        list.add(str);
    }

    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));

    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: This way the while loop never terminates because scan.nextLine() is always looking for input

Comment: @HarunFeraidon: There's no other way to do it. If you know the number of rows that you'll read then you can manually loop for a specific number of time.