# Program runs infinitely when inputting a multi-line String in JAVA (BlueJ) using Scanner

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, multiline, bluej

I wrote a program in BlueJ that accepts a **multi-line String** and its job is to print that String as a **single-line continuous String**.

Here's the code I wrote -

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class test
    {
        public static void main() 
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter String: ");
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            while(sc.hasNextLine())
            {
                s+=sc.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

When I run this program and give the following input by copy-pasting it into the BlueJ terminal -

```
10100101111011111111
00000000000000000000
01011101110110101111
```

the program runs infinitely and gives no output.

To check where the code was going wrong I changed it to -

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class test
    {
        public static void main() 
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter String: ");
            String s = sc.nextLine(), a = s;
            while(sc.hasNextLine())
            {
                System.out.println(s);
                s+=sc.nextLine();            
            }
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

However, the output I'm getting is -

```
10100101111011111111
1010010111101111111100000000000000000000
```

and after that the program runs infinitely without any output.

Can anyone fix my code so that it gives the proper output -

```
101001011110111111110000000000000000000001011101110110101111
```

Comment: Since you're reading from stdin you're program is simply waiting for a next line. You'll have to close it, that means give it an EOF (ctrl-d in unix/linux, ctrl-z in windows (I think))

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/16206876/1484621

Comment: Paste the input, then press the enter key again a few times