# how to stop while loop when taking input without words: "exit" etc

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have to take inputs until EOF (white space or end of line). For example:

```
1
2
3
4
// end of taking input
```

I'm using `Scanner` to take inputs. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206813/how-to-terminate-scanner-when-input-is-complete#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20exit%20program,control%20%2B%20c%20to%20exit%20program.&text=You%20can%20check%20the%20next,terminate%20entry(if%20any).)  solution.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> password = new ArrayList<>();
        String input;

        while (!(input = sc.nextLine()).equals("")) {
            password.add(input);
        }

        boolean[] lengthValidation = lengthCheck(password);
        boolean[] passwordContainCheck = containCheck(password);

        print(lengthValidation, passwordContainCheck);
    }
```

I can't use this, due to [uri](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en) does not take it variant of answer

```
while(true) {
   String input = sc.nextLine();
   
   if (input.equals(""))
       break;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to take inputs until EOF (white space or end of line).

Try the following.  One entry per line.  Terminate with an empty line. You can store them in a list and use them when the loop terminates.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String v;
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
while (!(v = input.nextLine()).isBlank()) {
    items.add(v);
}
System.out.println(items);
```

Comment: it take all lines except last one. For example:
2
1
3
it take first 2, but doesn't third

Comment: sorry, yes, it's fine, but it doesn't solve my problem with uri ( it gave me next:
```Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at Main.main(Main.java:74)```

Comment: You should provide more information on how you're using the input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for, Scanner take input until it meets an empty line, then the loop stop

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> password = new ArrayList<>();
    String input;

    while (true) {
        input = sc.nextLine();
        if (input.equals("")) break;
        password.add(input);
    }
```