# Scanner won't close

Tags: java, inputstream, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to scan String from my input stream, but it won't close. Here is my code:

```
public static String receive(int sid)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(servers[sid].getInputStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A");
    String s = sc.next();
    sc.close();
    return s;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible your program is getting stuck on this line:

```
String s = sc.next();
```

Have you tried using sc.hasNext() or sc.hasNextLine() to check for further data? Does the input data have an EOF character?

Also, this question may be of help: [Java Scanner won't "finish" reading input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816965/java-scanner-wont-finish-reading-input)